# Why can't I use constant expressions in some Wasm instructions that require numeric literals?

Tags: webassembly

Why can't I use constant expressions in some Wasm instructions that require numeric literals? Because it seems to me that they have the same effect, but constant expressions would be more flexible during the compilation.

The correct usage:

```
(i32.load8_u (local.get 0)))  ;; Correct usage.
```

The wrong usage with an error:

> error: unexpected token "(", expected a numeric index or a name (e.g. 12 or $foo).

```
(i32.load8_u (local.get (i32.const 0)))) ;; Wrong usage.
```

Why does WebAssembly design it like this? One reason I can come up with is for simplicity, any else?

Comment: It seems that simplicity is indeed the reason. There is an extended constant expressions proposal [1], but it doesn't seem to add the case that you are trying for `local.get`. Otherwise, the real answer is "it's like that in the spec [2], localidx is only an u32 or id"

[1] https://github.com/WebAssembly/extended-const/blob/master/proposals/extended-const/Overview.md

[2] https://github.com/WebAssembly/extended-const/blob/master/proposals/extended-const/Overview.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(i32.const 0)` is a separate *instruction* that produces a stack operand. The local index `0` to `local.get` is an *immediate* of that instruction itself (just like `0` is an immediate to `i32.const`). It wouldn't be useful to make it a stack operand, since the value has to be statically known anyway, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to validate the instruction nor to compile it to machine code or know its resulting type.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the pattern of ".const c" defines a constant expression, and the constant expression itself can be evaluated at compile time (statically), so it would be fine if we use a constant expression here instead of a literal numeric value, right? And the only concern is like you said, the side effect of ".const c" would matter here.

Comment: Well, .const is not a constant, it is an instruction that evaluates a constant. So it only makes sense in syntactic contexts that allow instructions, and instructions in turn only make sense in contexts where the result need not be known at compile time. Vice versa, if we allowed the index of local.get to be a stack operand, then the syntax would also allow any other instruction, it could not be meaningfully restricted to just .const instructions.